# If endomorphisms embed, does the vector space itself embed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, set-theory, provability

This statement is known to be independent of ZFC:
$
\def\qq{\mathbb{Q}}
\def\pow{\mathcal{P}}
\def\end{\mathrm{End}}
\def\inj{\hookrightarrow}
$

> Given any sets $S,T$, if $\pow(S) ≈ \pow(T)$ then $S ≈ T$.

So I was wondering whether the following 'algebraic' statement is also independent of ZFC:

> (★) Given any infinite-dimensional $\qq$-vector spaces $V,W$, if $\end(V)$ embeds into $\end(W)$ as a ring then $V$ embeds into $W$.

The motivation is to find some algebraic statement that has no set-theoretic flavour but is sensitive to set-theoretic assumptions.

I know that if GCH holds, then (★) also holds. *Proof*: For every $\qq$-vector space $V$ with basis $B$ we have that $\end(V)$ has the same cardinality as $(B×\qq)^B ≈ \qq^B$ (because $(B×\qq)^B$ $\inj (2×\qq)^{B×B}$ $≈ \qq^{B×B}$, and $B×B ≈ B$ if $B$ is infinite). Now take any infinite-dimensional $\qq$-vector spaces $V,W$ such that $\end(V)$ embeds into $\end(W)$. Let $B,C$ be bases for $V,W$ respectively. Then $\qq^B \inj \qq^C$ and so $2^B \inj \qq^B \inj \qq^C \inj 2^C$, and hence $B \inj C$ by GCH, yielding an embedding of $V$ into $W$.

But does ZFC already prove (★)? If not, is there some well-known set-theoretic axiom weaker than GCH that implies (★) over ZFC?

Comment: There were some questions about this sort of thing before, Tarski called it "weak power hypothesis" and I referred to it (on MO and then here) as "ICF", or Injective Continuum Function. Clearly, it's enough to prove the statement, so it's weaker than GCH. Note that if you require the bijection between $\mathcal P(S)$ and $\mathcal P(T)$ to be an order isomorphism, then $S$ and $T$ are in fact equipotent. I guess here you'd have to preserve some semi-ring structure?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes I just commented on Eric's answer that I meant to preserve the semi-ring structure. It's to make sure that the question isn't just about cardinality. At least, not obviously.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Yes $\text{End}(V)$ here denotes the endomorphism ring of $V$. I know that if we do not care about its structure then the whole question reduces to a cardinality question. But I am sort of curious if requiring to preserve this kind of algebraic structure might potentially make it 'robust' against the set-theoretic background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that a family of elements $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ a ring $R$ is a family of orthogonal idempotents if $e_i^2=e_i$ for all $i\in I$ and $e_ie_j=0$ for all distinct $i,j\in I$.  If $R=\operatorname{End}(V)$, then given such an family, each $e_i$ is a projection onto a subspace of $V$ and these subspaces are linearly independent (i.e., their sum is an internal direct sum).  Conversely, given any decomposition of a subspace $V_0$ of $V$ as an internal direct sum and a projection $p$ from $V$ to $V_0$, the compositions of $p$ with the canonical projections of $V_0$ onto its direct summands form a family of orthogonal idempotents of $\operatorname{End}(V)$.

It follows that $\operatorname{End}(V)$ has a family of $\kappa$ nonzero orthogonal idempotents iff $\kappa\leq\dim V$.  Such families are obviously preserved by injective ring homomorphisms, so if $\operatorname{End}(V)$ embeds in $\operatorname{End}(W)$, then $\dim V\leq \dim W$.

Comment: Interesting; I had not thought of recovering the dimension from the endomorphism ring.

Comment: @user21820: Incidentally, this is how you get the bijection between $T$ and $S$ from an isomorphism between their power sets.